# Doing a school project, can't get Area calculation right

Tags: java

I am working on a Java Lab for school. The purpose is to calculate the perimeter, area, and radius of circle r given a polygon with x # of sides and n length.

My Code:

```
public class RegularPolygon {

    private int myNumSides;         // # of sides
    private double mySideLength;    // length of side
    private double myR;             // radius of circumscribed circle
    private double myr;             //radius of inscribed circle


    /**
     * This is a default constructor creating a 3 sided polygon (triangle)
     * This means that myNumSides should be initialized to 3
     */
    public RegularPolygon() {

        this.myNumSides = 3;
    }


    /**
     * This is a parameter constructor with one int parameter and one double parameter
     * @param numSides This is a parameter that sets the # of sides for object RegularPolygon   
     * @param sideLength This is a parameter for the length of each side in object RegularPolygon
     */
    public RegularPolygon(int numSides, double sideLength) {

        this.myNumSides = numSides;
        this.mySideLength = sideLength;
    }


    /**
     * Private Method to calculate the radius of the inscribed circle
     * @return Nothing
     */
    private void calcr() {

        this.myr = 0.5 * this.getSideLength() * (1/(Math.tan(Math.PI / this.getNumside())));
    }


    /**
     * Private Method to calculate the radius of the circumscribed circle
     * @return Nothing
     */
    private void calcR() {

        this.myR = 1 / 2 * this.getSideLength() * (1 / (Math.sin(Math.PI / this.getNumside())));
    }


    /**
     * This is a method that calculates the Vertex Angle. The Vertex Angle is assigned to to the variable q
     * @return double Returns the double value of q, the vertex angle
     */
    public double vertexAngle() {

        double q = ((this.getNumside() - 2) / this.getNumside()) * Math.toRadians(180);
        return q;
    }


    /**
     * Method that calculates the perimeter of the polygon. The perimeter is assigned to the double variable perimeter
     * @return double Returns the double value of the perimeter
     */
    public double Perimeter() {

        double perimeter = this.getSideLength() * this.getNumside();
        return perimeter;
    }


    /**
     * Method that calculates the area of the polygon RegularPolygon
     * @return double Returns the double value of the area
     */
    public double Area() {

        double area = 1 / 2 * this.getNumside() * Math.pow(this.getR(), 2) * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / this.getNumside());
        return area;
    }


    /**
     * Getter method that returns the value of myNumSides
     * @return int Value of myNumSides
     */
    public int getNumside() {

        return myNumSides;
    }


    /**
     * Getter Method that returns the value of mySideLength
     * @return double Value of mySideLength
     */
    public double getSideLength() {

        return mySideLength;
    }


    /**
     * Getter Method that returns the value myR
     * @return double Value of circumscribed circle myR
     */
    public double getR() {

        return myR;
    }


    /**
     * Getter Method that returns the value of inscribed circle myr
     * @return double Value of inscribed circle myr
     */
    public double getr() {

        return myr;
    }
}
```

Everything is correct except for the calcR and calcr methods. For some reason the value returned is always 0.0. Not sure if I am using the Math methods incorrectly or something.

Here is my testing code:

```
   public class PolygonDriver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            RegularPolygon poly = new RegularPolygon(4, 10);
            System.out.println(poly.Area());
            System.out.println(poly.getR());
            System.out.println(poly.Perimeter());

        }
 }
```

After running it, I get:
0.0
0.0
40.0

What is wrong with my methods calcR() and calcr()?

Comment: @Raptor: This question is appropriate here. It explains the assigment, demonstrates a clear effort to complete the assignment including the relevant code, and asks a specific question with sufficient detail. Please read the [help/on-topic] guidelines before posting comments, so that you yourself understand the way this site works, and be more polite. Thanks.

Comment: So for your testing code, I want to make sure you know that you're not actually calling calcR or calcr.  I am asking because if you are inferring from you test cases that those are wrong because no version of myr or myR are being set, that's because those two functions are never called

Comment: I called the 2 methods in getR() and getr() but the result is still the same. I also tried putting it in the constructors to no avail.I'm unable to call it in the driver directly because those 2 methods have to be private

Comment: @KenWhite I strongly disagree with this. As I'm a lecturer, I don't want my students to seek for answers by asking others online. That's not a good way  in learning progress, as students will become too lazy to think. (p.s. don't delete my comments; that's very rude)

Comment: @Raptor: a) I didn't delete your comments, because I don't have the ability to delete your comments. b) As a lecturer, you can control your students, not those on the rest of the planet. c) I'll link again to the [help/on-topic], which **very clearly** says what the requirements are for homework questions here, and this post meets those guidelines, whether it meets your approval or not. d) If you feel  the [help/on-topic] guidelines are inappropriate, then post at [meta] to ask to have them changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calcr() and calcR are not being called anywhere in your code so myr and myR are never being set so you are getting the initialized value of 0.0

Comment: I tried calling calcR() in getR() and calcr() in getr() and it is still the same. I am unable to use the method in the driver as those 2 methods have to be private.

Comment: If they need to be private then they need to be called from a public method in your class or in an initialization method or constructor.

Comment: Your math was not working because you are doing integer division when you  do `1/2` The result of this is 0 if you want to do 1/2 you need to make one value a double by making it 1.0/2 this will return .5

Answer (score 1):

Besides not calling calcr() and calcR(), you should change the 1/2 in Area() and the calcR() to 0.5 so that you are working with the correct data type.